# How to run one lambda function after another has finished

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, cron

I have an aws lambda function which is running daily at same time as cron job and is generating cloudwatch logs. I have another lambda function that takes those cloudwatch logs and move it to S3. So I want that when my first lambda function finishes execution, the logs lambda function starts and pushes the logs to S3 bucket. Kindly suggest how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a Lambda function from another Lambda function through the AWS SDK. So your first function should call the second function when it is finished. Make sure to select the InvocationType "Event" when invoking the second function and do not add any callbacks to avoid having the functions run in parallel and paying twice.